# How to use "NameSpace" on Visualforce Page in salesforce?

Tags: apex, visualforce, developer, production, developer-edition

I have facing problems on the VF page when I've to use StanderdController on VF than how I get "namespace" before the default field in a package org.

Here "Charge_Item__c" is a custom object in salesforce. I have to use as a standard controller on VF page. When I access field value "{!Charge_Item__c.PopUp_Allow__c}" from the controller but It's working fine in "Developer" Org. but not working fine in a "Production" org.
So I think it's a "namespace" issue in the "Production" org.

So my question is how to access "namespace" on vf page when I use a custom object as a standard controller?

Let's see in Image below.

[image]

Comment: Once you create any namespace, it automatically reflects on the API name of Object. For e.g. if I've namespace named `light002` in my org and there is one object called as `Merchandise__c` then to use it in code, I would write something like this `light002__Merchandise__c`.

Comment: @RohitMourya  Thanks for your kind information, but I can't use it manually, I have to use dynamically because I don't know, what will be namespace in Production Org.
So could you tell me if you have knowledge about it, how we can use namespace on VF dynamically not manually?

Comment: use this query: `string np = [SELECT NamespacePrefix FROM Organization].NamespacePrefix;`

Comment: @RohitMourya So how we can use it on VF  , i want to use here {!'np'_Charge_Item__c.PopUp_Allow__c}

Comment: The API name of Object should be sufficient. It's always unique.

Comment: I want  to say I know it's unique but I want to use {! <namespace><object_Api-Name>.<Field_API_Name>} like this.
Did you get it ?